# Is the phrase ''a little bit'' superfluous?

Tags: phrases

What's the point of saying both words if one of them already implies a small amount of something? Doesn't it seem a bit redundant?

Comment: This general question [has been covered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97207/is-it-check-and-mate-or-checkmate/97263#97263) here many times.

Comment: Yes, it seems a little bit redundant.

Comment: @Soylent: But only a ***tiny** little bit*. I think this is a pointless question.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is superfluous, but it is designed to be that way for emphasis. It's not just a litle, or not just a bit, it is a little bit.

Comment: It's not even superfluous technically. There is no technical standard for superfluity; there isn't even one for regular fluity.

Comment: Yes, I struggle to understand what people mean by _technically_ in this sort of discussion. Sometimes it's _according to some rule somebody taught me once, which probably has no relation to how people speak_. Sometimes it means _according to a bogus theory of language where pragmatics doesn't exist_. Sometimes it means _if I pretend this is algebra instead of English_.

Comment: Superfluous = unnecessary, especially through being more than enough. Technically = according to the facts or exact meaning of something; strictly. In the strictest sense of language, the phrase "a little bit" is superfluous due to redundancy. A more technically accurate turn of phrase would "a very little." However, in the vernacular, "a little bit" communicates an emphatic idea (not just a little, a little **bit**).